# Retrieving data from neo4j and displaying it on a webpage

Tags: php, web, neo4j, cypher

- I am doing a mini project where in I have  a chain of users connected to each other using a knows relationship and certain advertisements assigned to the users based on their properties.
- I want to retrieve certain property value of the nodes  using cypher query  and show them directly on my webpage which is in .php
- Can you give suggestions regarding which methods would be best to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You'll most likely have to use the [PHP driver](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki) for Neo4j.

Or, [the REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html)

I would first recommend populating you database with all nodes and relationships. Then use the webadmin to try out cypher queries which return the exact results you are looking for. You can then use that query wither in the REST API or using the PHP driver and loop through the results on the server and display them on the webpage however you wish.

Answer (score 1):

For using Neo4j from PHP check http://neo4j.org/develop/php

In general Cypher is easy, check out the [online course](http://neo4j.org/learn/online_course) and the [ref card](http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher) to get up to speed.

For the domain you're looking for check out this [GraphGist](http://gist.neo4j.org/?8389170)

A cypher query you could use (top 5 ads for stuff your friends like):

```
MATCH (n:User)-[:KNOWS]->(friend:User)-[:LIKES]->(p:Product)<-[:AD_FOR]-(ad:Advertisement)
RETURN ad.content, count(*) 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```